# Get last child from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, children

I am trying to add rides to my firebase and I am using the following code:

```
dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
        databaseQuery = myRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(1)
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()


      databaseQuery.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
              var BuleiaId = 0
                for (snapshot in snapshot.children){
                    var viagem = snapshot.getValue(Buleia::class.java)
                    BuleiaId = viagem?.id!!
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        })

        dbref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {

            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {

                    for (userSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                        val user = userSnapshot.getValue(User::class.java)
                        if (user?.userId == firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid) {
                            var user = user?.userName
                            button = findViewById(R.id.ButtonAdicionaBoleia)
                            button.setOnClickListener {
                                

                                var id = BuleiaId+1
                                var rideDay = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.rideDay).text
                                var rideTime = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.rideTime).text
                                var driveFrom = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.driveFrom).text
                                var driveTo = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.driveTo).text
                                var pick1 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.pickUp_1).text
                                var pick2 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.pickUp_2).text
                                var pick3 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.pickUp_3).text

                                /*val sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                                val user_id = sharedPref.getString("user_id", "anonimo")*/
                                //var user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
                                val buleia = Buleia(
                                    id,
                                    rideDay.toString(),
                                    rideTime.toString(),
                                    driveFrom.toString(),
                                    driveTo.toString(),
                                    pick1.toString(),
                                    pick2.toString(),
                                    pick3.toString(),
                                    user.toString()
                                )
                                myRef.child(id.toString()).setValue(buleia)
                                buleiaCreated()
                                // myRef.setValue(buleia)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })

    }
```

How can I pass the values to the second firebase request? Or merge both toguether? I need the username from the table Users but I need the child from the table Buleia. The problem currently is that when creating new value Buleia is writting on the current one, I want to check the last Id on database that have been created so I can create a diferent ID

Comment: You have to put one call into other 
whichever field is required First then call that first and then on response do the next firebase call. Also get little information about singleValueEventListener because in valueEventListener you will get update every time when you make any changes

Comment: Can you do a code example please? I did not quit undertood what you meant.

Comment: Have you tried to add the second call to Firebase right inside the first one? I'm afraid you're not getting any results because of the asynchronous type of operation. Since you're using Kotlin, this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5) will definitely help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that you are using correct scope for your **`BuleiaId`** variable. Second, you can call either `get` or `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` for single fetch scenarios then you can add your second query by nesting into first one .

```
   databaseQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
          var BuleiaId = 0
            for (snapshot in snapshot.children){
                var viagem = snapshot.getValue(Buleia::class.java)
                BuleiaId = viagem?.id!!
                //your second query with BuleiaId  
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    })
```

using get() :

```
  databaseQuery.get().addOnSuccessListener{
      snapshot ->
      var BuleiaId = 0
        for (snapshot in snapshot.children){
            var viagem = snapshot.getValue(Buleia::class.java)
            BuleiaId = viagem?.id!!
            //your second query with BuleiaId  
        }
   }
```

you can also use push() that auto generate 120bits unique ids if it suits your logic.

Comment: Does not matter what I do the problem is always de same

Comment: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class ecgm.app.buleia.model.Buleia does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped.

Comment: at ecgm.app.buleia.activity.CreateNewBuleia$onCreate$1.onDataChange$lambda-0(CreateNewBuleia.kt:46)

Comment: How do i add that push?

Comment: you can use `push()` on any database reference or any specified child. `ref.push().setValue(...)` please visit [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) @FilipeCruz

Comment: for your no-argument error try annotating your data class with @IgnoreExtraProperties
 and add a default value to them.

Answer (score 0):

```
dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
databaseQuery = myRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(1)
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()


databaseQuery.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        var BuleiaId = 0
        for (snapshot in snapshot.children){
            var viagem = snapshot.getValue(Buleia::class.java)
            BuleiaId = viagem?.id!!
        }
        dbref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {

            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {

                    for (userSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                        val user = userSnapshot.getValue(User::class.java)
                        if (user?.userId == firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid) {
                            var user = user?.userName
                            button = findViewById(R.id.ButtonAdicionaBoleia)
                            button.setOnClickListener {


                                var id = BuleiaId+1
                                var rideDay = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.rideDay).text
                                var rideTime = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.rideTime).text
                                var driveFrom = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.driveFrom).text
                                var driveTo = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.driveTo).text
                                var pick1 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.pickUp_1).text
                                var pick2 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.pickUp_2).text
                                var pick3 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.pickUp_3).text

                                /*val sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                                val user_id = sharedPref.getString("user_id", "anonimo")*/
                                //var user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
                                val buleia = Buleia(
                                    id,
                                    rideDay.toString(),
                                    rideTime.toString(),
                                    driveFrom.toString(),
                                    driveTo.toString(),
                                    pick1.toString(),
                                    pick2.toString(),
                                    pick3.toString(),
                                    user.toString()
                                )
                                myRef.child(id.toString()).setValue(buleia)
                                buleiaCreated()
                                // myRef.setValue(buleia)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })
    }

    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
})
}
```

**I am not aware about your logic but here it is what I am telling you**